# Is this the correct PHP version of this CURL line?

Tags: php, curl

Sorry if this is obvious - I'm just not sure I have it right. I don't get any response back when testing. Is the below the correct conversion of the CURL script to PHP?

```
curl -X POST -u $APIKEY:$APISECRET \ https://api.application.io/v1/project/<projectname>
```

if APIKEY = 1234 and APISECRET = 1234

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.application.io/v1/project/myprojectname");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$12341234:$56785678");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it's basic authentication you want:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
              "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$APIKEY:$APISECRET")
));
```